# MySQL WorkBench - Applying my own function to a column of a stored table

Tags: mysql, function

I am working with MySQL Workbench 57.
I have a table "locdum" with coordinates stored.  I have something like the next table:

```
id |X_LV03  |Y_LV03 |longitud |latitud
1  |790000  |125560 |NULL     |NULL
2  |550000  |235400 |NULL     |NULL
3  |485000  |80000  |NULL     |NULL
4  |750000  |80000  |NULL     |NULL
```

I need to transform the "X_LV03" and "Y_LV03" coordinates into geographic in an automatic way. I need that after uploading the data into my database, the coordinates change in its correspondent table with a function that will run each time that new rows are upload into the table.

For achieving this, I developed one function to calculate the latitud and other to calculate the longitud:

For the longitud I have made this:

```
Delimiter // 
CREATE FUNCTION X_LV03ToLong (lon decimal)
returns decimal
BEGIN 
#declare longitud decimal;
declare east int; 
declare lon  dec ;    

 # constants that will be changed
set  
lon = 2.6779094;  

# select variables from the table
 SELECT X_LV03 into east FROM am.locdum; 

#logic of function 
 # Convert origin to "civil" system, where Bern has coordinates 0,0. 
 Set east = east - 600000,                                           
 # Express distances in 1000km units. 
 east = east /1E6,                                                

 # Calculate longitude in 10000" units. 
 lon = 2.6779094,                                       
 lon = lon + 4.728982 * east,
 lon = lon + 0.791484 * east * north,
 lon = lon + 0.1306 * east * north * north,
 lon = lon - 0.0436 * east * east * east,

  # Convert longitude and latitude back in degrees. 
 lon = lon * 100 / 36;                                            

 return lon; # Return new coordinates. 

 end; //
```

This is created successfully.
 Then I try to apply it to my field with:

```
 call X_LV03ToLong()    Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE am.X_LV03ToLong does not exist  0.000 sec

SELECT X_LV03ToLong(locdum.longitud)    Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'locdum' in field list  0.000 sec

SELECT X_LV03ToLong(longitud)   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'longitud' in 'field list' 0.000 sec
```

it keeps giving me errors: either the function doesn't exist or that the table/column do not exist.

What i am doing wrong, or what is missing?

Thanks in advance for any hint or help received.